# No significance in the multivariate tests

Tags: multivariate-analysis, manova, univariate, split-plot, mancova

Hope this question is not too stupid. I haven't taken the MANOVA course yet, but I need to figure out a problem right now. I am running a mix-model MANCOVA on SPSS.

I have no significance in the multivariate tests, but a significant interaction in one of the univariate tests. Does this significant interaction still count?

If not, what should I do if there is no significance in the multivariate tests?

Thank you.

Comment: See Chapters 5.5 and 6 in https://www.researchgate.net/project/Book-New-statistics-for-the-design-researcher